# Handlebars.js fails to handle extended character sets

Tags: html, handlebars.js, ascii

I am reading a string of characters from an API to render on a page using `Handlebars.js`. The string has multiple ASCII characters in it and only the content up to and including the first ASCII character is written to the page. The remainder of the string is not rendered.

This is the string of characters:

```
{"productName" : "Product Name&#8482; &#40;Subscription f&#252;r 1 Year&#41;",}
```

This string works:

```
{"productName" : "Product&#8482; Name &#40; 1 year&#40;s&#41; coverage for 5 Foos&#40;s&#41; &#41;"}
```

The resulting HTML that does not render entire string is:

```
<div class="myClass">
    <span>MyProduct™</span>
    <span>Next key/value pair</span>
</div>
```

HTML as it should be:

```
<div class="myClass">
    <span>MyProduct™ (Subscription für 1 Year)</span>
    <span>Next key/value pair</span>
</div>
```

My questions are: Is this related to the multiple ASCII characters causing a bug? And has anyone experienced this before and if so, what was their solution?

There are a few languages to deal with and this bug appears in English and other languages.

Thanks for any help.

I have a Fiddle but i have not been able to replicate the scenario exactly and of course this Fiddle example works as expected. I am not sure if it is because the object in the Fiddle is not exactly a JSON object and there for parsing differently?. Fiddle link [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m1ufv5kv/)

Also, this closer to the actual HTML:

```
{{#eulaItems}}
    {{#unless_blank eulaLink}}
        <div class="productEULA">
            <img src="https://xxx/misc/icon_pdf.png" alt="EULA" />
            <div class="eulaTextPos"> 
                <span>{{{productName}}}</span>
                <span>
                    <a href="{{{eulaLink}}}" target="_blank">$staticContent.get('Cart_Common.getEULAText')</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/unless_blank}}
{{/eulaItems}}
```

Comment: the object, that does not work has an extra `,` in it. This is introducing another key value pair. is that the problem or a typo?

Comment: In the object that does not work there is another key/value pair. next pair is: "eulaLink" : "//URL_here.pdf"  The whole object should be: "eulaItems" : [ {
    "productName" : "Product Name&#8482; &#40;Subscription f&#252;r 1 Year&#41;",
    "eulaLink" : "//My_URL.pdf"
  } ],

Comment: can you please add a working code sample exposing the issue?

Comment: I dont think the special chars are the issue. They are they same set of chars in both strings. thats why you should post a code sample that exposes the issue - not only the result.

Comment: I will work on getting a working code sample posted

Comment: you can use `JSON.parse()` on a string to simulate the parsing after ajax call returns